# The .vstemplate file expects to be added to a project item, but the item being added to this is not a project item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bots, application-settings

I am getting this Error when I am trying to setup the configuration on visual studio / Microsoft Bot framework. I was gone through the stages what said in the documentation. Can you help to proceed?

[image]

Comment: Copy the error, screenshots are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the path of the templates dont exist. Make sure that the path Visual Studio has set as the home of the templates is the same path you're placing the templates in.

**`Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions User project templates location`**

You can see where Visual Studio is looking for templates